# Read char by char and newline from text file in JAVA using FileReader

Tags: filereader, filewriter

i want to read character by character from file and write that character in another file, 
when the character is ";", i want to get the next line and continue read char by char

i used FileReader to read char by char and FileWriter for writing that char 
the problem is that i can`t get the next line in the file, the program just processes the first line only

any idea, please

thanks

Answer (score 0):

i have a solution to your problem :

```
 File inputFile = new File("in.txt"); 
 File outputFile = new File("out.txt"); 

 FileReader in = new FileReader(inputFile); 
 FileWriter out = new FileWriter(outputFile); 
 int c; 

 while ((c = in.read()) != -1) 
 {
     if (c == ';')
      out.write('\n');
     else
      out.write(c);
 }

 in.close(); 
 out.close();
```

If the first file contain :

```
hello;my;name;is;john
```

The second file will be :

```
hello
my
name
is
john
```

That's what you want?

If you have any questions you are welcome :)

Comment: Thank you :)
but the problem in reading,
 
the first file has : 
hello; \n
my;\n
name;\n
is;\n
john

it just writes hello in the second file, it dose not read the next line 
i don`t know how to get the next line in reading :(